# multi-condition based filtering of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```
let allRoles = ['role1', 'role2', 'role3', 'role4'];
let usedRoles = ['role2'];
let remainingRoles = allRoles.filter(role => !usedRoles.includes(role))
```

this returns remainingRoles = ["role1", "role3", "role4"]

but i want if any like role2, role3, role4 are there in usedRoles array except role1 then remainingRoles must return something like this

```
remainingRoles = ["role3", "role4"]
```

means don't want role1 to be there & also if usedRoles = ['role1'];

then remainingRoles = [] should return an empty array

Comment: Sounds a bit unclear still what you want to achieve. Perhaps your filter can be `allRoles.filter(role => !usedRoles.includes("role1") && !usedRoles.includes(role))`?

Comment: rather let remainingRoles = allRoles.filter(role => role !== "role1" && !usedRoles.includes(role)) from what I understand

Comment: or let remainingRoles = allRoles.filter(role => !["role1", ...usedRoles].includes(role)) if you want to keep it tidy

Comment: there is multi role registration where user can register with more than one role & there is some limitations that if user registers with role2 then user can further register with roles like role3, role4 but not role1 same case if user registers initially with role1 then user cannot further register with any other role anymore.

Comment: is that related to the role number ?

Comment: no it is related to particular role for example four roles are ['admin', 'client', 'employer', 'agent']

Comment: then I guess a data structure stating this rule would be more appropriate than a string to describe the role

Comment: if user registers as admin he cannot register anymore for other role & same if user registers with any role except admin can register with other roles also except admin want to make such array.

Comment: Is there an inclusion relationship between those roles ?

Comment: no relationship its just more over condition requirements

Comment: Can update your question, and mention if `usedRoles` is this then the desired output is this and list some possibilities so that others can have a clear picture.

Comment: then why not make this exclusion part of the model eg role{ name: "admin", excludes: ["employee", "client", "agent"] }